# Server IP Getting Indexed, Redirect to Domain + Path in HTAccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Google is indexing my servers IP address, causing duplicate content issues.  I want to redirect the IP address to the domain, but preserve the URL path.  I have tried this, but it redirects all URL's with the IP address to the homepage:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.ridepros\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ridepros.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ridepros.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I would prefer to redirect the user to the correct URL, not the homepage. I've tried this, but I get server 500 errors when I paste it into the HTaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !208\.113\.243\.229\(?<silo>[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\W*\S*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ridepros.com/$1
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Only `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.ridepros\.com$` `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ridepros.com/$1 [L,R=301]` should suffice. Try clearing your browser cache first, because 301's are cached aggressively by browsers. Your code should work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried only those two lines of code and it still redirects everything to the homepage. I cleared browser cache and tried multiple browsers too.

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ridepros.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this, but it still redirects to the homepage: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.ridepros\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ridepros.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for reference, I found this in a Webmaster World thread, it fixed my issue..

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3} [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/3390524.htm